# How does java swing fix the percentage size of the JTextArea so that it doesn't change?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I am developing a GUI interface using Java Swing's GridBagLayout, in which I use JTextArea, which I set to 40% on the left side after adding it to the JScrollPane, and a JList on the right side after adding the JScrollPane to 60%. When I first opened the JTextArea and the JList components were normal, but when I pasted text into the JTextArea, the size of the JTextArea changed, which bothered me for a long time.

I would like to ask the gods of stackoverflow how to solve this problem. How to guarantee that no matter what I type in JTextArea, no matter how big the form is, JTextArea is always guaranteed to be 40% and JList is always guaranteed to be 60%.

[image: The interface after first opening the program]

[image: The size of the JTextArea changes after the text is entered]

Sometimes, when I maximize the window and minimize it may change for a while, and then for a while JTextArea's broadband will be stretched out again. It's really upsetting and I don't know what to do about it.

I use GridBagLayout, I don't know if something is not adjusted properly.

[image: the program code snippet 1]

[image: the program code snippet 2]

At first, I thought it was the problem of GridBagLayout parameter setting. Other people had set weightx to 1.0, so I also set it to 1.0. In the beginning, I used 0.4 and 0.6. Both are set to 1.0, so that the ratio is 50%, but this does not help, the size of the JTextArea will still be widened after entering the text. I adjusted it back.

Others say to use new JTextArea(20,10) to specify rows and columns, but I've tried that too and it doesn't work.

[image: I updated the dynamic effect of the JTextArea image]

I found the reason, this is the code, and the reason is that I added the insert and change and delete listening events to the textArea. I added a function to these events to set the content of the JLabel to the number of words in the TextArea, and then this happened. But I haven't solved it yet.

```
package jlist.demo;

import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea;
import org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextArea;
import org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextScrollPane;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestWinFrame2 extends JFrame {

    RTextArea textArea;
    RTextScrollPane scrollForTextArea;

    RTextArea textArea2;
    RTextScrollPane ScrollForTextArea2;

    JPanel leftPanel;

    JList jList;
    JScrollPane listScrollPane;

    JLabel wordNumberLabel;
    JToolBar toolBar;

    public TestWinFrame2() {
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        toolBar = new JToolBar(JToolBar.HORIZONTAL);

        // Add the toolbar to the panel, not the frame or contentPane
        GridBagConstraints bag = new GridBagConstraints();
        bag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST; // Adjust the position of the toolbar
        bag.gridx = 0;
        bag.gridy = 0;
        bag.gridheight = 1;
        bag.gridwidth = 2;
        bag.weightx = 1.0; // Make the toolbar span the whole width of the panel
        bag.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; // Make the toolbar fill the horizontal space
        wordNumberLabel = new JLabel("word-count");
        toolBar.add(wordNumberLabel);

        add(toolBar, bag);


        textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea();
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        scrollForTextArea = new RTextScrollPane(textArea);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_ScrollForTextArea = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea.gridx = 0;
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea.gridy = 1;
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea.gridheight = 1;
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea.weightx = 0.3d;
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea.weighty = 0.5d;
        add(scrollForTextArea, gbc_ScrollForTextArea);


        textArea2 = new RSyntaxTextArea();
        textArea2.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea2.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        ScrollForTextArea2 = new RTextScrollPane(textArea2);
        textAreaAddInsertListener();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_ScrollForTextArea2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea2.gridx = 0;
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea2.gridy = 2;
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea2.gridheight = 1;
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea2.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea2.weightx = 0.3d;
        gbc_ScrollForTextArea2.weighty = 0.5d;
        add(ScrollForTextArea2, gbc_ScrollForTextArea2);

        jList = new JList();
        listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_listScrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_listScrollPane.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc_listScrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_listScrollPane.gridx = 1;
        gbc_listScrollPane.gridy = 1;
        gbc_listScrollPane.gridheight = 2;
        gbc_listScrollPane.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc_listScrollPane.weightx = 1.0d;
        gbc_listScrollPane.weighty = 1.0d;
        add(listScrollPane, gbc_listScrollPane);


        setSize(1200, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void textAreaAddInsertListener() {
        textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("insertUpdate---------------");
                wordNumberLabel.setText(textArea.getText().length() + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("removeUpdate---------------");
                wordNumberLabel.setText(textArea.getText().length() + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("changedUpdate---------------");
                wordNumberLabel.setText(textArea.getText().length() + "");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestWinFrame2();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use a [JSplitPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) to set the initial dimensions, but the user can change them.

Comment: Put the text area into a scroll pane of its own. The text area will want to change its size based on the text

Comment: LineWrap has been set to True and placed in the JScrollPane

Comment: *LineWrap has been set to True and placed in the JScrollPane* - so the problem is solved? If not, then post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem after following the suggestions given here.

Comment: I updated the dynamic effects of JTextArea images, I started by adding JScrollPane and LineWrap to True. The problem persists. I'm trying something new. I'm not sure it'll work. I'm testing it

Comment: (1-) an image tells us nothing about your code. Post your [mre] so we can copy/paste/compile/test the code to see the behaviour you describe.

Comment: *JTextArea is always guaranteed to be 40% and JList is always guaranteed to be 60%.* - not of the default layout managers are designed to do this exactly. You can approximate it by using 60/40 as the weightx constraint for the two components. But remember that this weighting only applies to the "extra" space available after each component is displayed at its preferred size. You could use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/) which is specifically designed to handle relative sizes.

Comment: I posted the problematic code, which was caused by JTextArea insert, delete, change events, but I have not yet resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

One simple, kind of "klugy" solution

```
public MyGridBagLayout extends GridBagLayout {
  public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
    super.layoutContainer(parent);
    // Now check the TextArea is the taking up the correct amount of space
    // And if not, adjust it and the Component to the right
  }
}
```

Like I've already admitted, this is a kludge. But IMO the time you spend learning to master Swing is time better spent learning CSS 3.

Comment: This method seems stupid, if other methods are really not enough, I will consider this one

Comment: @apython Are you still looking for a better solution than this?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the upper left text area is scrollable horizontally.  If you add that, the textarea shouldn't resize anymore, yes?

```
new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED)
```

I use an old Sun layout class called VariableGridLayout that I modified to do variable width columns.  I imagine RelativeLayout is probably an option, too.